# what is the use of public, private, protected class where it can be access via reflection class?

Tags: php, oop

Something which is made for security purpose and encapsulation that we have the `Public,Private, Protected` classes but one question is still struck in the mind that what is the mean of that if we still can access or know those all the members of class whatever it is `Public, Private` or `Protected`??

For Example :

```
<?php

 class GrandPas   // The Grandfather's class
  {
   public     $name1 = 'Mark Henry';  // This grandpa is mapped to a public modifier
   protected  $name2 = 'John Clash';  // This grandpa is mapped to a protected  modifier
   private    $name3 = 'Will Jones';  // This grandpa is mapped to a private modifier
  }
#Scenario: Using reflection

$granpa = new ReflectionClass('GrandPas'); // Pass the Grandpas class as the input for the Reflection class
$granpaNames=$granpa->getDefaultProperties(); // Gets all the properties of the Grandpas class (Even though it is a protected or private)



 echo "Printing members the 'reflect' way..<br>";

 foreach($granpaNames as $k=>$v)
  {
    echo "The name of grandpa is $v and he resides in the variable $k<br>";
  }
```

the output will be:

```
#Scenario Using reflection
Printing members the 'reflect' way..
The name of grandpa is Mark Henry and he resides in the variable name1
The name of grandpa is John Clash and he resides in the variable name2
The name of grandpa is Will Jones and he resides in the variable name3
```

As we can see the all members of the class whether its `Private, Protected or Public`. So what is the concept of OOP here?

PS: Example take from Shankar Damodaran.

Comment: "Reflection is often used as part of software testing, such as for the runtime creation/instantiation of mock objects." From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)).

Comment: Designing classes that later for sure will be used via reflection is not a way of design. You use reflection on the class for the purpose of your own application, e.g. a test suit, not the opposite.

Comment: You say they're for “security purpose”s, but they aren't. Access specifiers are designed to prevent you from doing something stupid on accident, not to provide any measure of security against a determined attacker.

Comment: I need to agree with @WaleedKhan ... anyone that can instantiate your class, already has its source and know about its properties

Comment: then why we use `protected or private` if we have the class access

Comment: for purpose of good design, good looking code and later reuse. Using public is bad. Imagine you have `public $x` in your class. Later in your application you do `echo $yourClassObject->x`. Later you go to this class and change `$x` to `$y`. The echo, then, doesn't work. That's why for instance introducing accessors and setting the field private is the better practice

Comment: @RoyalBg yeah thats pretty clear answer for this, thanks for clearing my huge misconception about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## TL;DR;

*If you **can** do something - that does not mean you **should** do it*

**Reflection**

That's the thing which is intended to provide meta-information about entities, but real use-case for it is debatable and almost always it can be replaced with something. The point is not to tell that it's bad, but to tell - if you want to use that in your architecture, then probably, you have a flaw in it.

**A way to "go"..**

Actually, you can access protected/private properties in PHP without using `Reflection`. For instance, [`Closure::bindTo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php) like:

```
class Test
{
   private $x = 'foo';
}

$z = new Test();

$y = function()
{
   return $this->x;
};
$y = $y->bindTo($z, $z);

echo $y(); //foo
```

And.. so what? Each language feature may be used for good or bad. That we're calling "good practices" and "bad practices" (well, to be honest, it's hard for me to remember "good practices" for such things as `global` in PHP, but that's out of this question). More, in PHP there are so many thins which you can use in wrong way - that it makes it *difficult* language - in the sense, that it's not hard to learn the language, but it's hard to use all it's features properly, because that requires solid architecture & good practices knowledge.

You may imagine a way to access hidden properties with even such thins as [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var_dump) + [`ob_`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) functions - but that will only illustrate how horrible may be using of some decent feature.

**And how to deal with it**

Do not use `Reflection` in such way. And certainly don't count on this when building your architecture. It's not the thing for which it should be used. And if you want to access your properties from outside - then - fine, declare them as `public`.

Just use things properly. It's the only way to go. And if you don't know what is the proper usage - then learn. It's the thing we're always doing. Each day.

Comment: Thanks a ton for clearing my doubt here, really a good example.

Answer (score 3):

The `public`, `protected` and `private` tokens are meant to define *visibility* for properties, it's not meant to provide security in any way.

Visibility is used to distinguish between:

1. your public interface,
2. the interface exposed to class extensions, or,
3. internal state.

Reflection is primarily meant as an aid to provide goodies such as AOP, DIC, proxies, etc.; specifically, it's not meant as a hacker's tool. Someone using your code can simply read it to get what they want, nay, edit it for their own "evil" purposes.

Comment: then there is a misconception about `public` `private` or `protected` among the OOP concept that its mainly used for security purpose.

Comment: @SudhanshuSaxena I'd be interested to know which article mentions such a thing; they're clearly advocating the wrong idea :)

Comment: Moreover, many documentation generators provide an option to hide private fields and methods. This is good for making public API documentation with only `public` methods fields and classes.

Comment: @janek2012 Right, that's an example of how visibility can be useful as well :)

Comment: I would also add, that reflection is used in DI container implementations (to analyze the class' constructor), which do not relay on configuration.